# Computer won't turn on motherboard or cpu

Tags: windows, windows-xp

After a frozen screen when I tried to restart my machine all I got was PSU power up for 5 seconds, a single beep and shut down.

My PC configuration :
Asus m2n32 sli deluxe m2
nforce590sliwifi-ap solo
ATX mainboard
AMD Athlon tm 64x2 5000+ cpu socket am2

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like there is a short. Check all connections.  Verify what a singe beep means in the manual for the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's overheating. I would let it sit for a couple of hours and see if it comes to life. Check the CPU fan and clean out the dust.